How to configure code indentation in VSCode?
I would like to clarify a question about VSCode indentation.
My employee is using the Prettier extension for code formatting.
A function that was supposed to look like this:
function evaluateCandidate(age, salary, experience, educationLevel) {
  if (age < 18) {
      return "Age below the minimum required.";
  } else if (age > 65) {
      return "Age above the allowed limit.";
  }
  
  if (salary < 3000) {
      return "Salary below the minimum acceptable.";
  } else if (salary > 10000) {
      return "Salary above the maximum acceptable.";
  }
  
  if (experience < 2) {
      return "Insufficient experience.";
  }
  
  if (educationLevel !== "Bachelor's Degree" && educationLevel !== "Master's Degree" && educationLevel !== "PhD") {
      return "Education level not met.";
  }
  
  return "Candidate approved!";
}

Is being formatted like this:
function evaluateCandidate(
    age,
    salary,
    experience,
    educationLevel,
  ) {
  if (
    age < 18
  ) {
    return "Age below the minimum required.";
  } else if (
    age > 65
  ) {
    return "Age above the allowed limit.";
  }

  if (
    salary < 3000
  ) {
    return "Salary below the minimum acceptable.";
  } else if (
    salary > 10000
  ) {
    return "Salary above the maximum acceptable.";
  }

  if (
    experience < 2
  ) {
    return "Insufficient experience.";
  }

  if (
    educationLevel !== "Bachelor's Degree" &&
    educationLevel !== "Master's Degree" &&
    educationLevel !== "PhD"
  ) {
    return "Education level not met.";
  }

  return "Candidate approved!";
}

For a simple function like this, it might not make much difference. But in a large project, it makes a significant impact because other employees waste time adjusting the indentation and trying to understand what this ****** is doing.
I would like to know if there is a way for other employees to configure something to remove or override Prettier’s indentation.
If there is no way, I will need to dismiss him.
I have already tried configuring Prettier to undo the default settings it applies, but it doesn’t work.

If there is no way, I will need to dismiss him - seriously?? Over formatting?

decide on a consistent formatting approach and make everyone use it. if you don't set a standard, then you'll get disagreements like this.

First of all please be nice to your employees,
I understand your frustration, but dismissing an employee over Prettier’s formatting seems extreme.
Can you try adding a file named .prettierrc.json to the root of your project with the following content ...
{
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 5000
}

This file is going to configure prettier to increase characters per line  into 5000 characters per line to avoid line breaks
I hope this works
